# What are "uneven attempts"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

From [this](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/06/01/politics/trump-white-house-racial-unrest-leadership/index.html) sentence:

> And given Trump's **uneven** attempts to unite the nation in the past, he would face a huge assignment in making a meaningful impact, not to mention his habit of undermining his own scripted addresses with follow-up tweets that reignite controversy.

What did the author mean by deeming Trumps' attempts **uneven**?

Oxford defines **uneven** as "not having the same quality in all parts".

If the definition above is the one which fits this context does that mean some of Trump's attempts lacked strength, insistence, firmness?

Thanks!

Comment: Some attempts were better than others, in the view of the writer. It does not say how.

Answer (score 1):

> And given Trump's *uneven attempts* to unite the nation in the past...

According to [this](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uneven) link, "uneven" can be defined in the following way:

> **uneven:** varying in quality (eg, *an uneven performance*)

Here, calling a performance "uneven" implies that it's *inconsistent* and varies in quality from time to time. *Trump's attempts* are described in a similar way. You could translate the sentence like this:

> And given Trump's *inconsistent attempts* to unite the nation in the past...

Answer (score 1):

The definition you use is appropriate in the context of the quote, but it only points to inconsistency in Trump's attempts, rather than evaluating their merits or deficiencies. However, given Trump's record in this regard, I would view the use of "uneven" as pure irony. An ironic synonym for abysmal. Following your link, I see that the quote is from CNN, which makes abysmal a certainty.